# React callback onClick Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

Below is my parent component which handles the `state` of the app.

```
 function App() {   
    const [teamData, setTeamData] = useState<any | undefined>(undefined);
    return(
      <> 
          <Teams teams={teams} onTeamClick={() => setTeamData(team)} />
          <Modal teamData={teamData} />
      </>
    )
}
```

Next is my component which passes the state back up the tree. However, I am getting the following typescript error:

> Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

```
type Props = {
   teams: any[];
   onTeamClick: () => void;
}

function Teams({teams, onTeamClick}: Props) {
   return(
     <div>
       {teams.map(team => {
         // the error is coming from onTeamClick
         // No error if I change it to onTeamClick={onTeamClick}
         <Team name={team.name} onTeamClick={() => onTeamClick(team)} />
       })
     </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because here:

```
<Teams teams={teams} onTeamClick={() => setTeamData(team)} />
```

you are taking the `team` variable from nowhere, therefore it is `undefined`.

Doing this should be fine:

```
<Teams teams={teams} onTeamClick={ team => setTeamData(team) } />
```

I am not super familiar with React Hooks, but I think you might be able to do this, which is a bit shorter:

```
<Teams teams={teams} onTeamClick={ setTeamData } />
```

Comment: Trying the first one, but still seem to get the same error. With the second one how will I pass the `team` in with this ?

Comment: the second example is written in point-free syntax https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-point-free-composition-will-make-you-a-better-functional-programmer-33dcb910303a

Answer (score 1):

It is `undefined` because the initial state from the hooks leads the compiler to believe it could possibly be `undefined`.

How about trying this ?

```
<Team name={team.name} onTeamClick={() => onTeamClick && onTeamClick(team)} />
```